# How can SQL sysadmin get to "forbidden" areas of Windows

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

Logging in as administrator to Window 2008 R2 I can access all files on the server, naturally.

If I then login to SQL Server 2008 R2 as `sa`, I cannot access ***some*** flat files, for example, to Restore or dump data via bcp. (I ***can*** access all flat files via Import/Export Wizard though.)

I end up moving backup files around the file system until I find somewhere that works, or dumping data files to places I would prefer not to use.

How do I give sysadmin rights to these forbidden folders?

Why would my predecessor have blocked sysadmin access to these areas, do you think?

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you are logged into SQL server as SA, you are the admin for SQL server, not the Windows server itself.

You are constrained to what the SQL server service account has rights to access on the machine as that is the context in which SQL server runs.

To be able to access these windows locations from within SQL server, first identify the name of the service account that is actually running the SQL server service and then give the permissions on the folders to this account.

To find the SQL Server service account, you can query the sys.dm_server_services DMV to find the account:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_services
```

This will show you the service account set for each service, alternatively, you could just look in either the services console in Windows or SQL server configuration manager to see what account the SQL server is logging on as.

This DMV was introduded in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, so won't work in earlier versions, the following article has some information on various ways to find the service account:

[Get SQL Server Service Account using T-SQL](http://sqlandme.com/tag/sys-dm_server_services/)

Comment: How do I identify the name of the service account that is actually running the SQL Server?

Comment: Have added a section to the answer indicating how this can be done

Comment: Thx @steoleary.  
I get Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.dm_server_services'.
I have found the server service user via Windows

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using, 2008 or 2008 R2?  I think this DMV was introduced in a service pack for 2008 R2, can't remember the exact version it appeared in first, you can also use xp_instance_regread to find it in earlier versions, but it's easy enough to find from windows.

Comment: We're using 2008r2.

After finding the user name it's just a question of Windows Explorer>right-clicking the head of the folder cluster to change>Properties>Security>Edit>Add/validate the SQL service user>OK>Highlight added user>Allow whatever permissions>OK>OK...

I'm still not clear WHY anyone would setup SQL server without file permissions for sysadmin.

But thank you.  Lesson learnt!

Comment: It's good practice to set up your service accounts with as low a privilege as possible, we set up all our servers so that the account only has access to the SQL server directories created at install time and one specific share where we can put backup files, generally the server doesn't need to access anything outside these areas, and if it does we just assign individual permissions to that account, not blanket ones across the machine.